# CSS How do i repeat a background image horizontally and always keep it at the bottom of a webpage?

Tags: css, repeat, background-position

I am new to CSS and am tinkering with a few options. I want a pic called 'toplayer.jpg' to be repeated horizontally at the bottom of my webpage. I have used this code in an external style sheet. The pattern repeats horizontally...however it floats to the top of the page.

```
body {
    background-image: url("../Images/toplayer.jpg");
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Any suggestions for this noob would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your background declarations should work, I guess the issue is that the body tag has no height :

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url("https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg");
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Also for what it's worth, it doesn't display the background image at the bottom of the page, but at the bottom of the *viewport*. A workaround for this is to use a wrapper `<div>` within `<body>` and to add background image to that element..

Comment: @HashemQolami I think if OP wants the background to show at the bottom of the page the best would be to remove the height on the body tag and let it flow with it's content.

Comment: @web-tiki Yes, but on body and html as well.